# Why dotnet test tool is not creating code coverage report?

Tags: powershell, dotnet-test, coverlet

My project structure is the following:

```
.
├── Application
├── Application.Core
├── Application.Domain
├── Application.Tests
├── Application.IntegrationTests
└── README.md
```

And the command to run my test I use the following input:

```
dotnet test $folder.FullName -c Release --no-build /p:CoverletOutput='$root\coverage' /p:MergeWith='$root\coverage.json' /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover
```

where `$folder` is pointing to my Application.Tests path: `C:\projects\coredemoapp\CoreDemoApp.Tests` and `$root` to `C:\projects\coredemoapp\`

All the tests are run successfully. However, the problem is that `coverage.json` nor `coverage.opencover.xml` files are not created.

I also tried to use `coverlet` directly with the following command:

```
coverlet <path to test.dll> -
-target "dotnet" --targetargs "test --no-build" --merge-with $root\coverage.json --format opencover
```

, everything works on my local machine with explicit path to the dll. But in the case of running the command with the previous `$folder.FullName` as the `<path to assembly>`, coverlet assumes a path to the **debug** dll, not **release** version as it should and fails.

[Link to the full build script](https://github.com/ariksman/CoreDemoApp/blob/master/build.ps1)

Comment: At least a partial solution is to take advance of the coverlet --targetargs and pass it the release parameter: `--targetargs "test -c Release --no-build"`

Answer (score 30):

Basically I forgot to add the coverlet msbuild [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/coverlet.msbuild/) into my test project. After that, all worked fine with the following command:

```
dotnet test $folder.FullName -c Release --no-build /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutput=$root\coverage /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover
```

Comment: I think argument would be `--targetargs "test [path to test project].csproj --no-build"`  instead of `--targetargs "test -c Release --no-build"`

Comment: what is /p: used for? Im a bit confused

Comment: @ajr Worked perfectly with `coverlet.msbuild`. Strange that `coverlet.collector` is included in a new test project but not `coverlet.msbuild`.